# Page not working in IE 7 and 8??? Menu position incorrect

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

My Site: http://www.soskin.zxq.net/incorporate.php, http://www.soskin.zxq.net/estate.php

If you look at these two pages you will see that the distance between the logo and the menu is different then say in this page which is correctly displayed http://www.soskin.zxq.net/history.php. The menu is a list the ul of the list has the class nav and has the following attributes:

```css
.nav{
    float: left;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Why is that it works fine on one page but not the other. Notice both pages have forms so it is possible the forms are affecting this. I have experimented for hours IDK how the forms affect it. Do any of you know any IE glitches that could be causing this.

Also my menu is a dropdown menu and if you hover over about it should display.The text in that display also looks wrong (offseted incorrectly). For this I'm planning to create an alternate IE style sheet, however maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Maybe you have modified your code since you posted the question, but I don't see any difference between the three pages in IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well... idk but you can at any rate do something like this:

```css
.nav {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 675px; /* this will force the width */
}
```